# Blob trigger is not working in azure

Tags: azure-webjobs

I am trying write small webjob code in azure to queue the name of blob file when blog is added to container. My Job host is getting started but does not react when blob is added using manually/programmatically. I am not sure how to debug it. I did some search and followed the suggestion to wait for 10 minutes, in fact I waited for few hours but no luck. Following is log

```
06/01/2015 18:19:11 > 1bb5b4: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[06/01/2015 18:19:12 > 1bb5b4: SYS INFO] Run script 'WebJob1.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[06/01/2015 18:19:12 > 1bb5b4: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[06/01/2015 18:19:13 > 1bb5b4: INFO] This is with blob
[06/01/2015 18:19:14 > 1bb5b4: INFO] Found the following functions:
[06/01/2015 18:19:14 > 1bb5b4: INFO] WebJob1.Functions.ProcessQueueMessage
[06/01/2015 18:19:14 > 1bb5b4: INFO] Job host started

Following is my code

public static void QueuePhoneForNewblob(
[BlobTrigger("myshop/{name}")] string input,
string name,
[Queue("myshop")] out string message)
{ 
    message = name;
    Console.WriteLine("hello world");
}
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("myshop")] string logMessage, TextWriter logger)
{
    logger.WriteLine(logMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it, I was about to use  worker role and getting ready with some dirty code; anyway I moved my trigger functions to functions.cs file which was previously there in program.cs